# The following error occurred while running the live server in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, liveserver

Problem summary: one Div element generates three elements at Live server.

p tag is just divider for normal thing and abnormal things.

Ineffective measure:

1. Reinstall the Live server plug-in
2. Re-booting the VSCode
3. Re-booting My Mac

Please, conform my code.

HTML Code:
[image]

CSS Code:
[image]

Description of local server:
[image]

Comment: Live server doesn't seem to be the problem here.
Aside from `css/main.css` you are also using `js/main.js` and `reset.main.css`. Both of these could change the layout of your page. Remove them first and make sure that the problem persists.

Comment: Also, do not paste your code as an image next time. It's much easier to answer your question if the code can be copy-pasted and executed locally.

Comment: @DorinBotan Thanks for your comments. First of all, I apologize for attaching the code as an image. This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow. Also, my development studies are just beginning, so I hope you understand.
In conclusion, this issue was solved by deleting the translation plugin for the Chrome browser. I was lucky. 
Thank you again for thinking about how to solve the problem with me. Good luck Dorin!